# Need to find laptop HDD enclosure for this drive

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, enclosures

[This is the drive](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=5fb658a3fd20a110VgnVCM100000f5ee0a0aRCRD) is have, will any 2.5" sata enclosure [like this one](http://www.mwave.com.au/sku-16040447-A_Power_2_5%22_SATA_HDD_Enclosure_Aluminum_Black) be fine?

What size are laptop hdd's 2.5" or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, however, those cheap enclosures usually don't last long.

I had one of those, and always had intermittent connectivity problems.

Laptop drives are 2.5''

Answer (score 0):

Note that while 2.5" laptop hard drives are a uniform size in length and width, they can vary in height.  Slim drives are often 12.5mm high and sometimes even thinner, but they used to also have 19mm tall drives.  This may be less common today, but I do recall in the past having to be very careful with my laptops that took 12.5mm drives.  You may want to make sure that the case you are getting, particularly if it is especially small, is large enough to hold the height of the drive.